# In Java, how to get all static fields in a typed list as objects of their class (and NOT as Field instances)?

Tags: java, reflection

I need to iterate through a list of static fields of a class (say, `MyClass`). These fields are all of the type java.util.regex.Pattern. Using reflection, I can get all the static fields as follows:

```
MyClass mc = new MyClass();
List<Pattern> patternList = new ArrayList<Pattern>();
for (Field f : Commands.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
    if (Modifier.isStatic(f.getModifiers())) {
        // add the Pattern corresponding to the field f to the list patternList
    }
}
```

Now, since I know that all the fields `f` are of the type java.util.regex.Pattern, I want to create a `List<Pattern>` containing all of them. How can I do that?

I haven't found any question that matches mine, although there are several questions on SO about reflection. I apologize if my question is a repetition.

Comment: Thanks for doing 90% of the work in your question. =)

Comment: I like to work hard in search of an answer before I ask for help on SO. People such as yourself make this place a center of intellectual joy :)

Comment: To those who marked this as duplicate, PLEASE READ THE QUESTION FIRST. It is NOT the same as the question that has been linked with "This question already has an answer here". That question simply wants the Field objects, while I want to retrieve the original object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
patternList.add((Pattern)f.get(null));
```

(Regarding the phrasing of your question, the field `f` is of type `Field`, but it has a target that has type `Pattern`.)

Reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html

Comment: The `Field` class doesn't seem to have any method called `get()`. And, of course, a `Field` object cannot be casted into `Pattern` directly, so `(Pattern) f` is not possible.

Comment: According to the documentation I cited, `Field` certainly has `get()` - unless we're talking about different classes. Regarding the cast, I mean `(Pattern)(f.get())`. Could you clarify about your situation a bit more?

Comment: seems correct (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#get(java.lang.Object))

Comment: I think you need to supply a null argument to the get call. If it were an instance field, the argument would be a reference to the target object.

Comment: Oh right, I forgot about static fields versus instance fields. Thanks Patricia!

Comment: I am looking at the link you provided, and I don't see any method `get()`. The closest is `get(Object obj)`. I apologize for sounding stupid, but, I don't see how this method is useful (unless I have misunderstood the documentation).

Comment: I have edited the answer to use `get(null)`. Would you need an explanation of how that works?

Comment: Ah, got it! I just tried with `null` (mostly out of frustration), and came back to reply on SO. And then I saw this discussion. Thank you, Nayuki and Patricia.

Comment: Also, @ChthonicProject Nayuki didn't write `(Pattern)f`. He wrote `(Pattern) f.get()`, which means the downcast applies to the result of `f.get()`.

Comment: @NayukiMinase, if you could provide an explanation of how this method works, that would be great! The official Java documentation just confused me a lot :-(

Comment: In Java, there are lots of objects flying around. There's a `Class` object to represent the `Commands` class that you created. Using the `Class` object, you requested an array of `Field` objects. Each `Field` object corresponds to a field declared in class `Commands`. The reason you get a bunch of `Field` objects instead of the field values is that a `Field` object can contain properties like the name of the field, public/private/static/etc., the type, and more.

Comment: So naturally, you want to call `get()` to get the value of the field, right? Not so quick. If the field is static, like `Math.PI`, then it only has one value. But if the field wasn't static, like (hypothetically) `myString.length`, then the field needs to be associated with an instance. So you would call `f.get(myString)` to mean the same as `myString.length`.